# Hide a gridview header column without losing position of other header columns vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, header

I would like to hide the header for two columns on a gridview. However I would like the other column headers to remain in their original position not move across to where the hidden columns would have been.

The code I'm using to hide the headers is the following:

```
For colCount As Integer = 0 To 1
    gvProgressGrid.HeaderRow.Cells(colCount).Visible = False
Next
```

In the below example the headers should start at the column that contains the first set of blue cells.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of toggling visibility, you can just set the column headers to empty strings and remove the border.

```
For colCount As Integer = 0 To 1
    gvProgressGrid.HeaderRow.Cells(colCount).Text = ""
    gvProgressGrid.HeaderRow.Cells(colCount).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
Next
```

If you want to retain the column header value, you could also just set the cell's foreground color equal to it's background color.

```
For colCount As Integer = 0 To 1
    gvProgressGrid.HeaderRow.Cells(colCount).ForeColor = gvProgressGrid.HeaderRow.Cells(colCount).BackColor
    gvProgressGrid.HeaderRow.Cells(colCount).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
Next
```

Comment: Hi @smoore, thanks for the suggestion. This kind of works, but the problem is that the gridview border remains around where the cells originally displayed. I can set the gridview border to 0px, however, this means that none of the outside edges of the outer cells have a border. What I would like it to look like it how the right edge of the above images looks, but obviously on the left side not the right.